# I keep getting the wrong output for my Monty Hall game stimulator in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to recreate the Monty Hall game ([here is a description of the game)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MontyHallProblem.html)
Where it will ask the user to enter a number (my code asks to 'Enter a random seed') to begin, if the user doesn't enter a number, the game will display an error message. If the user does enter a number, the game will start. The game will then ask the user how many times they want to test the game so if the user says 5, then the game will repeat five times and it will ask the user AGAIN once it completes all five games. However, if the user enters a string/non-number like "five" then the game should ask the user to enter a number until the user finally does enter a number.

***Here is an example of what the input could be***

```
25
5
exit
```

***Here is what the output SHOULD be***

```
Enter Random Seed:
Welcome to Monty Hall Analysis
Enter 'exit' to quit.
How many tests should we run?
Game 1
Doors: ['G', 'C', 'G']
Player Selects Door 1
Monty Selects Door 3
Player should switch to win.
Game 2
Doors: ['C', 'G', 'G']
Player Selects Door 1
Monty Selects Door 2
Player should stay to win.
Game 3
Doors: ['G', 'C', 'G']
Player Selects Door 2
Monty Selects Door 1
Player should stay to win.
Game 4
Doors: ['C', 'G', 'G']
Player Selects Door 1
Monty Selects Door 2
Player should stay to win.
Game 5
Doors: ['G', 'C', 'G']
Player Selects Door 3
Monty Selects Door 1
Player should switch to win.
Stay Won 60.0% of the time.
Switch Won 40.0% of the time.
How many tests should we run?
Thank you for using this program.
```

***Here is what MY program outputs***

```
Enter Random Seed:
Welcome to Monty Hall Analysis
Enter 'exit' to quit.
How many tests should we run?
Please enter a number:
How many tests should we run?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "monty.py", line 16, in <module>
    tests = int(input('How many tests should we run?\n'))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

***Here is my code***

```
import random
G=0
G2=0
C=0
try:    
    random_seed = input('Enter Random Seed:\n')
    random_seed = int(random_seed)
    print('Welcome to Monty Hall Analysis')
    exit = input("Enter 'exit' to quit.\n")
    while True:
            if exit == 'exit':
                    print('Thank you for using this program.')
                    break
            try:
                    tests = int(input('How many tests should we run?\n'))
                    tests = int(tests)
            except ValueError:
                    print('Please enter a number:')
                    continue
            select_door = ['G', 'C', 'G']
            random.shuffle(select_door)
            player_door = int(input('Doors: '+str(select_door)))
            if random.shuffle(select_door) == "['G', 'C', 'G']":
                    G = 1
                    C = 2
                    G2 = 3
            elif random.shuffle(select_door) == "['C', 'G', 'G']":
                    C = 1
                    G = 2
                    G2 = 3
            elif random.shuffle(select_door) == "['G', 'G', 'C']":
                    G = 1
                    G2 = 2
                    C = 3
            if player_door == C:
                    print('Player should stay to win')
            else:
                    print('Player should switch to win')
            doors = [1 , 2 , 3]
            random.choice(doors)
            print('Player Selects Door: ', player_door)
            print('Monty Selects Door: ', random.choice(doors)) 
except ValueError:
    print('Seed is not a number!')
```

Sorry if my code is really bad or if it doesn't make sense. I'm a new programmer.Also, I am just trying to get the actual game to work before I can work on the % stay won and the % switch won part.

Answer (score 1):

You put this piece of code inside a infinite loop that's why it is called everytime

```
try:
    tests = int(input('How many tests should we run?\n'))
    tests = int(tests)
except ValueError:
    print('Please enter a number:')
    continue
```

Here's my fix:

```
import random
G=0
G2=0
C=0
try:    
    random_seed = input('Enter Random Seed:\n')
    random_seed = int(random_seed)
    print('Welcome to Monty Hall Analysis')
    exit = input("Enter 'exit' to quit.\n")
    while True:
        if exit == 'exit':
                print('Thank you for using this program.')
                break
        try:
                tests = int(input('How many tests should we run?\n'))
                tests = int(tests)
        except ValueError:
                print('Please enter a number:')
                continue
        stay_cases = 0
        switch_cases = 0
        for _ in range(tests):
            select_door = ['G', 'C', 'G']
            random.shuffle(select_door)
            player_door = int(input('Doors: '+ str(select_door)))
            if random.shuffle(select_door) == "['G', 'C', 'G']":
                    G = 1
                    C = 2
                    G2 = 3
            elif random.shuffle(select_door) == "['C', 'G', 'G']":
                    C = 1
                    G = 2
                    G2 = 3
            elif random.shuffle(select_door) == "['G', 'G', 'C']":
                    G = 1
                    G2 = 2
                    C = 3
            if player_door == C:
                    print('Player should stay to win')
                    stay_cases += 1
            else:
                    print('Player should switch to win')
                    switch_cases += 1
            doors = [1 , 2 , 3]
            random.choice(doors)
            print('Player Selects Door: ', player_door)
            print('Monty Selects Door: ', random.choice(doors))
        print('Stay Won {}% of the time.'.format((stay_cases/tests) * 100))
        print('Switch Won {}% of the time.'.format((switch_cases/tests) * 100))
except ValueError:
    print('Seed is not a number!')
```

I have added `for _ in range(tests)` and the main game engine should run `tests` times.

I also implemented the part where it says `Stay won ... of the time`

The code I gave you should do the job, however, it will crash if the user pick a door that is not one of the provided doors. To avoid this, you can use `if player_door not in doors` to check whether the user selection is one of the provided ones.